# Who is Monica Cellio?

Tags: discussion

Who is Monica Cellio?

I’m new here and not familiar with why there are so many questions regarding her. 
I can’t find her on SE either.

Comment: I wonder, where did you first read/saw something about Monica?

Comment: _"I can’t find her on SE either."_ Huh?? https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio

Comment: I'm somewhat uncomfortable having the answer to "Who is Monica Cellio?" as [link to recent unpleasant events].  What about all her positive contributions over the years?

Comment: @Rebecca well without those unpleasant events, nobody would be wondering about her like that, so it's unavoidable.

Comment: Monica Cellio is a thoughtful and considerate individual who has volunteered countless hours of her time to helping moderate a half-dozen different Stack Exchange sites. Everything else is minutiae.

Comment: I’m new go SE. It’s only natural I don’t understand.

Comment: @Shadow The Burning Wizard, it came up as one of the hot questions on the site about SE’s declaration about her or something. I’m really sorry to hear about her though.

Comment: @Dora fair enough. Hope you got your answer, and now with over 20 rep you can join chat to discuss it further if you like, and not in comments. :)

Comment: I did, thank you. Where is the chat section?

Comment: [An account of what transpired](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFiQPkdb5Qs&lc=UgzzH7ULmytO6-qi8HV4AaABAg).

Comment: VTR as I think the answer to this question could be an expanded version of @DoubleAA 's statement

Comment: @topo or a verbatim quote. As I said, everything else is minutiae. A random Google searcher that comes here need know nothing more than what I said.

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree that the 'recent events' don't deserve to have equal prominence to Monica's years of freely-given service. But I'm sure there are plenty of people who might have many remarks about the high quality of that service that would help the OP - and others - understand the situation better. Answered in that spirit, a question like this could also redress the record somewhat wrt what people find when they google this topic.

Comment: @topo in Hebrew we have an expression תפסת מרובה לא תפסת. You grab too much and you haven't grabbed [at all]. We could write pages of quality anecdotes and descriptions of praise about Monica, but I'm not sure that helps a random googler who won't bother to read it. Short and sweet does the trick